# Speed issues with While loops in SQL stored procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, while-loop

I'm taking over some code that is trying to store a list of IDs at one time and I find this code to be running quite slow for the actions we are trying to complete. Plus, in certain occasions resulting in deadlocks due to high amounts ids.

```
USE [store]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateImagePriority]

   @separator CHAR(1),
   @filename  varchar(50),
   @parentId   int,
   @slaveIds varchar(8000)

   AS
   BEGIN      
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      DECLARE @SLAPriorityint
      DECLARE @separator_position INT 
      DECLARE @array_value VARCHAR(50)

      SET @slaveIds = @slaveIds + @separator
      SET @SLAPriority= 0

      WHILE PATINDEX('%' + @separator + '%', @slaveIds ) <> 0
           BEGIN

               SET @SLAPriority= @SLAPriority+ 1

               SELECT  @separator_position = PATINDEX('%' + @separator + '%',@slaveIds )
               SELECT  @array_value = LEFT(@slaveIds , @separator_position - 1)

               SELECT  Array_Value = @array_value

               SELECT  @slaveIds = STUFF(@slaveIds , 1, @separator_position, '')

               UPDATE image_info
               SET SLA_PRIORITY = @SLAPriority
               WHERE FILE=@filename and EXT_PAR_ID=@parentId   and SLA_ID=@array_value
           END
      SET NOCOUNT OFF
   END
```

This is a sample of what we would pass in:

e.g.

```
separator = ','
filename = 'burgerking'
parentId = '1859'
slaveIds = '15,16,19,20,21,25,28,29,30,38,99'
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the speed of this code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a table-valued function to split your values into a table. Then all you need is a single `UPDATE .. FROM .. JOIN` statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateImagePriority]
   @separator CHAR(1),
   @filename  varchar(50),
   @parentId   int,
   @slaveIds varchar(8000)
AS

set @slaveIds = @slaveIds + @separator
;WITH SplitString AS
(
    SELECT
        1 ID,LEFT(@slaveIds,CHARINDEX(',',@slaveIds)-1) AS Part,RIGHT(@slaveIds,LEN(@slaveIds)-CHARINDEX(',',@slaveIds)) AS Remainder
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID+1,LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)-1),RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX(',',Remainder))
        FROM SplitString
        WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)>0
)
update i
SET SLA_PRIORITY = s.ID
from splitstring s
join image_info i on i.[FILE]=@filename and i.EXT_PAR_ID=@parentId and i.SLA_ID= s.Part
where s.Part > ''
```

For SQL Server 2000, or just to make the string splitting re-usable, I lifted [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703/573261) from another question.

```
create function dbo.SplitString 
    (
        @str varchar(8000), 
        @separator char(1)
    )
    returns table
    AS
    return (
        with tokens(p, a, b) AS (
            select 
                1, 
                1, 
                charindex(@separator, @str)
            union all
            select
                p + 1, 
                b + 1, 
                charindex(@separator, @str, b + 1)
            from tokens
            where b > 0
        )
        select
            p Id,
            substring(
                @str, 
                a, 
                case when b > 0 then b-a ELSE 8000 end) 
            AS Part
        from tokens
      )
GO
```

Then your SP becomes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateImagePriority]
   @separator CHAR(1),
   @filename  varchar(50),
   @parentId   int,
   @slaveIds varchar(8000)
AS

update i
SET SLA_PRIORITY = s.ID
from dbo.splitstring(@slaveIds,@separator) s
join image_info i on i.[FILE]=@filename and i.EXT_PAR_ID=@parentId and i.SLA_ID= s.Part
where s.Part > ''
GO
```

Comment: Nice use of a CTE query to separate the comma string.  But it would be better in a function so it is reusable...

Comment: You're right. I think of `no-trace` queries all the time but if he's creating a procedure, he could well create a function at the same time.

Comment: Hey Richard this is working fine in my local database but when I try to use it on the live database it returns with an error:"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UpdateImagePriority, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.". I'm assuming its an issue with the version of SQL Server its running (8.0.2055)?

Comment: *More information its running SQL 2000 and I don't think "with"s are in the supported list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to convert the array into an XML document, which is then easy to return as a single column table of integers:

```
use tempdb
go

create function dbo.ParseIDs(@ids varchar(max), @separator char(1)) returns @rtn table (
  id int
)
as
begin
  declare @xml xml

  set @xml = '<root><n>' + replace(@ids, @separator, '</n><n>') + '</n></root>'

  insert into @rtn
  select id.value('.', 'int')as id
  from @xml.nodes('/root/n') as records(id)

  return
end
go

declare @buf varchar(max) = '15,16,19,20,21,25,28,29,30,38,99'
select * from dbo.ParseIDs(@buf, ',')
go

drop function dbo.ParseIDs
go
```

This returns the following:

```
id
----
15
16
19
20
21
25
28
29
30
38
99
```

It would be easy to then to do something like this:

```
UPDATE image_info
SET SLA_PRIORITY = @SLAPriority
WHERE FILE=@filename and EXT_PAR_ID=@parentId   and SLA_ID in (
  select id from dbo.ParseIDs(@array_value, ',')
)
```

This might even be better:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    tbl.SLA_PRIORITY = @SLAPriority
FROM   dbo.ParseIDs(@array_value, ',') as x
       inner join image_info tbl on x.id = tbl.SLA_ID
WHERE  tbl.FILE=@filename and tbl.EXT_PAR_ID=@parentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a set based update:

```
    USE [store]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateImagePriority]

   @separator CHAR(1),
   @filename  varchar(50),
   @parentId   int,
   @slaveIds varchar(8000)

   AS
   BEGIN      
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      DECLARE @SLAPriorityint
      DECLARE @separator_position INT 
      DECLARE @array_value VARCHAR(50)

      SET @slaveIds = @slaveIds + @separator
      SET @SLAPriority= 0

      DECLARE @slaveIdTable Table
      (
        ids INT,
        SlaPriority INT
      )
      WHILE PATINDEX('%' + @separator + '%', @slaveIds ) <> 0
           BEGIN

               SET @SLAPriority= @SLAPriority+ 1

               SELECT  @separator_position = PATINDEX('%' + @separator + '%',@slaveIds )
               SELECT  @array_value = LEFT(@slaveIds , @separator_position - 1)

               -- get table of ids
               INSERT INTO @slaveIdTable (ids,SlaPriority) VALUES(@array_value,@SLAPriority);

               SELECT  @slaveIds = STUFF(@slaveIds , 1, @separator_position, '')

           END

    UPDATE ii
        SLA_PRIORITY = @SLAPriority
    FROM image_info ii
    JOIN @slaveIdTable st ON st.ids = st.SLA_ID
    WHERE
        st.[FILE] =  @filename AND
        st.EXT_PAR_ID = @parentId                   

      SET NOCOUNT OFF
   END
```

Richard's answer is a bit more elegant.  Didn't see it while I was working on mine.